# How can I create a PyTorch tensor with all zeroes and a 1 in the middle of the third dimension?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor, `torch.Size([161, 161, 11])` and I want to set it all to zeroes, which I can do with: `self.conv1.weight.data = torch.zeros(self.conv1.weight.data.size())`

Except, I want column 6 (the middle) of the third dimension to be all ones. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign it afterwards:

```
self.conv1.weight.data[:, :, 6] = 1.0
```

Or in case this tensor is trainable:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    self.conv1.weight.data[:, :, 6] = 1.0
```